# How to add days to a current date and format in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to make a function that takes today's date and add more days. For example, if todays' date is 10/09/20 and I add 5 days I want to return 15/09/20.

I want to format the result as such:

> 15 Sep

I've created the following function:

```
function calcDate(days){
  var curDate = new Date();
  
  var estDate = curDate.setDate(curDate.getDate() + days);
 
  return estDate.getDate() + ' ' + estDate.getMonth();
}
```

However, I get the error  `estDate.getDate() is not a function`.

If I just return `estDate` I also get an unformatted number, eg: `1608685587862`

I've tried several approaches from Google and Stack Overflow but none work.

Would anyone know what I am to do?

Comment: See docs for setDate(), it doesn't return Date object. Returns milliseconds

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Date.prototype.setDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) returns the milliseconds of the result, which is a number, not `Date` object.

You can also instead add the equivalent milliseconds of those days to the current time to calculate the desired date:

```js
function calcDate(days){
  var curDate = new Date();
  
  var estDate = new Date(curDate.getTime() + days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
 
  return estDate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', { month: 'short', day: 'numeric' });
}

console.log(calcDate(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost there! You're using the correct date methods: `.setDate()`. It's just the formatting that's left.
You can use Moment JS to format the date.

```js
function calcDate(days){
  var curDate = new Date();
  
  var estDate = curDate.setDate(curDate.getDate() + days);
 
  return moment(estDate).format('DD/MM/YY');
}
console.log( calcDate( 5 ) );
console.log( calcDate( 10 ) );
console.log( calcDate( 20 ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-rmZcZsyhe0/MAjquhTgiUcb4d9knaFc7b5xAfju483gbEXTkeJRUMIPk6s3ySZMYUHEcjKbjLjyddGWMrNEvZg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

setDate() will return date value in milleseconds, you need to parse it again as date.
In your example you no need to use an additional variable "estdate" you can use the "**curDate**" variable after you set the date.

**Note:** Date.getMonth() will return zerobased month i.e. for september it will return 8.

```
function calcDate(days){
  var curDate = new Date(); 
 curDate.setDate(curDate.getDate() + days); 
  return curDate.getDate() + ' ' + (curDate.getMonth()+1);
}
console.log(calcDate(1));
```

Here is the [Demo](http://www.toolbow.com/code-editor/42c9a922-9674-46ca-803f-f270a85dece8/add-days-to-current-date) (See JavaScript Tab)